# OOP PHP extended class multiple includes

Tags: php

I am learning OOP techniques, so please don't be too harsh if my question sounds too basic ^_^
I have 4 php files.

```
index.php
parentClass.php
childClass1.php
childClass2.php
```

childClass1.php and childClass2.php basically extend the parentClass.php. So my question is does the index.php file call the parentClass twice if I include or require both child classes in the index file? For example something like:

```
require_once("childClass1.php");
$child1 = new childClass1();
require_once("childClass2.php");
$child2 = new childClass2();
```

Comment: [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) / [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) / [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register).

Comment: I guess, you're looking for [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: If each childclass file contains a `require_once("parentClass.php");` then "No"... that's what the `once` of `require_once` means.... but look at autoloading

Comment: Please **do NOT** downvote questions because they are basic! Downvote only if it's badly formatted or shows no research effort at all. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how `parentClass.php` is loaded.

Unless you use `require_once` or `include_once` the file will be included multiple times, which in return will lead to a Fatal Error, as each class may only be defined once.

If you are using an autoloader the file will only be included once, as it will only load unknown classes.